# Laravel Relation in multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables like below.

**Table A**

```
id  | val_a
1   | a1
2   | a2
3   | a3
```

**Table B**

```
id  | id_a| val_b | id_c
1   | 2   | b1    |  1
2   | 2   | b2    |  3
3   | 3   | b3    |  4
```

**Table C**

```
id  | val_c
1   | c1
2   | c2
3   | c3
4   | c4
```

What is the best way to get data like below :

```
 [
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_a] => 1
        [val_a] => 'a1'
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_a] => 2
        [val_a] => 'a2'
        [table_b_c] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id_b] => 1
                        [val_b] => 'b1'
                        [id_c] => 1
                        [val_c] => 'c1'
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                     (
                        [id_b] => 2
                        [val_b] => 'b2'
                        [id_c] => 3
                        [val_c] => 'c3'
                     )
            )
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_a] => 3
        [val_a] => 'a3'
        [table_b] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id_b] => 3
                        [val_b] => 'b3'
                        [id_c] => 4
                        [val_c] => 'c4'
                    )
            )
    )
]
```

**Model for TableA**

```
class TableA extends Model {

    public function getTableA($id_a) {
        return $this->where('id', $id_a)->with('TableB', 'TableC')->get()->toArray();
    }
}
```

**Model for TableB**

```
class TableB extends Model {

    public function tableA(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\tableA'); 
    }

    public function tableC(){
       $this->belongsTo('App\tableC'); 
    }

}
```

**Model for TableC**

```
class TableC extends Model {
}
```

I have tried above relation but it not work for me.

I am using `Laravel 5.2`. And achieve this by foreach loop. But I don't know what is the best way to do. Can I do this by laravel or Mysql ? Thanks Ahead.

Comment: What is failing with the Relations?

Comment: Seems your Models are wrong. Model B should have  `$this->belongsTo('App\ModelA', 'id_a');` and `$this->belongsTo('App\ModelC', 'id_c');` functions. The second function in model A should be in model C. Then loop with `$a->tableBs()`

Comment: @ Martin Henriksen my relation through "id_a not found in TableC"

Comment: @louisav I have create both function in tableB but how to relate it?

Comment: Your hasMany relations would prefer a plural function name. Update the question with your new model changes please.

Comment: @louisav  I have update model in question please assist.

Comment: I have little knowledge of laravel model. please tell me what should I do in modelC.

Comment: @ louisav Sorry I am not getting you.

Comment: I didn't consider the return data you need. Don't have an answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've setup some data my side and used [this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to return a nested object.

Your model function names must be labelled correctly, then this will work:

```
$data = TableA::with(['recordsB.recordC'])->get();
dd($data->toArray());
```

This means that all TableA records will be fetch, it then adds all the records from table B related to each A record. As long as the function name in the model is recordsB. The `dot` syntax then adds the nested and related records from table C (for each B record), given the correct function name once again. See "Nested Eager Loading" in the documentation.

The data you're depicting seems it's not for a specific A record. So better to have the eager loading in a controller perhaps. For this reason I removed the id parameter from `getTableA` function.

In models - model TableA:

```
class TableA extends Model {

  public function getTableA() {
    $data = TableA::with(['recordsB.recordC'])->get();
    return $data;
  }

  public function recordsB(){
    $this->hasMany('App\TableB'); 
  }
}
```

Model TableB:

```
class TableB extends Model {
   public function recordA(){
      $this->belongsTo('App\TableA'); 
   }

   public function recordC(){
      $this->belongsTo('App\TableC'); 
   }
}
```

Model TableC:

```
class TableC extends Model {
   public function recordsB(){
      $this->hasMany('App\TableB'); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am creating service for angularjs. So I don't have blade page. please answer as api only

Comment: your updated answer is not return required result. it return tableB and tableC in seprate array fields.

Comment: in tableB you're not repeating an id_c. Please clarify relation. Does each C record have many B records?

Comment: Can you please write function in models for above answer.